# ngrx EffectsModule makes Http service undefined

Tags: angular, typescript, ngrx, ngrx-effects

Using `@ngrx/effects` v4.0.5 with Angular v4.4.4.

When I import `EffectsModule` in `app.module.ts`, the Http service becomes undefined.

Some code:

```
// app.module.ts
import { BrowserModule, Title } from '@angular/platform-browser';
...
import { HttpModule, Http } from '@angular/http';
...
import { EffectsModule } from '@ngrx/effects';
import { AuthenticationModule } from './authentication/authentication.module';
import { MyEffects } from './myEffects.ts'
...

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    HttpModule,
    ...
    AuthenticationModule,
    StoreModule.forRoot(reducers),
    EffectsModule.forRoot([MyEffects])
  ]
  ...
})
export class AppModule { }
```

**Please note that `MyEffects` isn't related in any way to the authentication feature.**

When I use the first thing I can use in my app, the sign in button, I call AuthenticationService.signIn, which in turn calls its http instance `this.http.post(...`

And `this.http` is undefined (got an error message, looked into it via debugger, and found it undefined - `this` is not undefined and has a `http` property which is undefined)

If I comment out `EffectsModule.forRoot([MyEffects])`, the http service "reappears" and the sign in works.

**Please note that `MyEffects` isn't related in any way to the authentication feature.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upgrading the `@angular/` packages from `4.4.4` to `4.4.5` solved the problem O_O'